# What are the advantages to use StringBuilder versus XmlDocument or related to create XML documents?

Tags: .net, xml, xmldocument, stringbuilder

This might be a bit of a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), but I have seen it is some production code, namely the use of [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) as opposed to [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) when creating XML documents. In some cases these are write once operations (e.g. create the document and save it to disk) where as others are passing the built string to an XmlDocument to preform an [XslTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx) to a document that is returned to the client.

So obvious question: is there merit to doing things this way, is it something that should be done on a case-by-case basis, or is this the wrong way of doing things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend using [XMLTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) to build up XML documents which (quote from MSDN):

> Represents a writer that provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only way
>   of generating streams or files
>   containing XML data that conforms to
>   the W3C Extensible Markup Language
>   (XML) 1.0 and the Namespaces in XML
>   recommendations.

I've used it numerous times - more performant than using XMLDocument, with the XML-safety you don't get with StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

XmlDocument is a pain to use for creating XML so most folks do not bother to use it.  StringBuilder is light weight but does not know XML so doesn't validate structure at all.  You can get the best of both worlds with LINQ to XML.  It allows you to author valid XML easily without much goofy overhead.  Check out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387019.aspx) if you are not familiar with the use of Linq to XML to author XML.

Comment: +1 XDocument/XElement are your friends.  Also if using VB.NET for this is an option at all XML Literals are even easier http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2008/02/07/vb-net-9-0-xml-literal.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068%28vs.80%29.aspx#vb9overview_topic6

Comment: It's pretty easy to build "porcelain" on top of System.Xml that eliminates the fiddling and offers convenient methods for everything. I personally like this approach much better than using LINQ, or any declarative-style solution.

Comment: Well, XDocument/XElement is that porcelain.  It Let you quickly build up proper XML, is namespace aware etc.  Much better than StringBuilder.  Much easier to use than XmlDocument.  That's one of the key advantages of using LINQ to XML (though the ability to query over the XML is very nice too).